# Most efficient way to get an object from a 3D Graph

Tags: java, data-structures

So, I am making a game, and I have a problem. I need some way to efficiently get the objects that are located in the 3d graph.

However, the problem is that they all can cover more than one value to get. So, for example, the value 'foo' might cover the x range 400-500, y range 10-20 and the z range 30-60.

I am wondering whether there is a more efficient way to store and get these then by just storing them in a Array and searching through them, something I would prefer not to do, because of the large amount of these values.

This is for selecting biomes for a game. However, I chose to put this here versus GameDev because this seemed to be more of a data structures question. I might be wrong however, and if I was would gladly close this and open one there.

Is there any other way to do this?

```
public static Tile getTile(int height, int moisture, int temperature) {
    for(Tile tile : tileList){

        boolean isTile = true;

        if(!(tile.heightMax > height && tile.heightMin < height)){
            isTile = false;
        }

        if(!(tile.temperatureMax > temperature && tile.temperatureMin < temperature)){
            isTile = false;
        }

        if(!(tile.moistureMax > moisture && tile.moistureMin < moisture)){
            isTile = false;
        }

        if(isTile){
            return tile;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my searching method. As you can see, I am using a list to store all of the tiles, and searching for the one that fits the criteria. Is there any other way to do this with many tiles as fast as possible?

Comment: Hash tables are very good at providing quick lookup of objects, but I'm a little lost on the structure of your data to really say if that's a viable solution. What have you tried?

Comment: The implementation isn't clear; when you say "by just storing them in a Array", how are you storing them? A code fragment showing how the values are being stored would help users better answer the question.

Comment: I have tried using arrays to store and lookup. This is for selecting biomes for a map, and each of the biomes has a height, temperature, and moisture level. I want the terrain generation to be as quick as possible, so I need some way to get the biomes quickly for the given height, temperature and moisture. If you need more info, just ask. I am not very good at giving what you guys might need, sorry about that.

Comment: @RobertBain Edited to include the implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I've solved this issue in the past is to define regions that represent an area of 3D space and then store a map to each object from all regions an object's space overlaps. Then when you want to find objects at a location you first use the map to find all objects that overlap that location's region before iterating through them looking for objects at that location.

Let me give you a code view of that. To build the region map:

```
Map<Region, List<Item>> regionMap = new TreeMap<>();
```

When an item is added:

```
item.getOverlappingRegions().forEach(region -> {
    if (!regionMap.containsKey(region))
        regionMap.put(region, new ArrayList<>());
    regionMap.get(region).add(item)
});
```

Then when you're searching for an item at a location:

```
if (regionMap.containsKey(location.getRegion()) {
    regionMap.get(location.getRegion()).stream()
        .filter(item -> item.contains(location))
        ....
}
```

There's definitely overhead in this but it is very fast for searching if your regions are sufficiently small.

This is designed for 3D spaces but it can be expanded to as many dimensions as you want: it is all in the implementation of the `Region` and `Location` classes.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure that I have understood what your problem is, but it seems very similar to a collision detection algorithm in 3D space. If this is the case, Octrees might be what you are looking for: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/108761/Octrees